# Batch converting SVG to PNG in Inkscape doesn't work

Tags: windows, svg, png, inkscape

I want to convert multiple SVG files in the folder `C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\svg` to 512x512 PNG files with the name `[SVG File Name].svg.png`.

I tried the following command:
`for /f %f in ('dir /b "C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\svg"') do inkscape -z -e %f.png -w 512 -h 512 %f`

The command line detects the SVG files correctly and goes through them but Inkscape says the following:

```
C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\inkscape>inkscape -z -e [SVG File Name].svg.png -w 512 -h 512 [SVG File Name].svg

** (inkscape.exe:8412): WARNING **: Can't open file: [SVG File Name].svg (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape.exe:8412): WARNING **: Can't open file: [SVG File Name].svg (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape.exe:8412): WARNING **: Specified document [SVG File Name].svg cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)
```

I opened one file in the normal Inkscape program, and it worked.

Comment: Used absolute path.

Comment: @zengr: As far as I can see, this happens also with the absolute path, in Inkscape 0.92.4.

Answer (score 2):

For SVG to PNG conversion I found cairosvg (https://cairosvg.org/) performs better than ImageMagick. Steps for install and running on all files in your directory.

```
pip3 install cairosvg
```

Open a python shell in the directory which contains your .svg files and run:

```
import os
import cairosvg

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".svg"):
        name = file.split('.svg')[0]
        cairosvg.svg2png(url=name+'.svg',write_to=name+'.png')
```

This will also ensure you don't overwrite your original .svg files, but will keep the same name. You can then move all your .png files to another directory with:

```
$ mv *.png [new directory]
```

Comment: Thanks for this post.
Please add
import cairosvg to imports which caused me some issues to find out

Comment: yeah. I did that, also I improve the script with an additional if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape is a good program.
Sometimes we don't understand the possibilities it has.
For better performance, you should use shell mode.
This mode consists of 2 steps:

1. Create a file, with the commands to execute.
2. Run this file using `type .\command.txt | inkscape --shell` where `command.txt` your file name, in windows console or bash.

All commands located in `action-list`, after typing `inkscape --shell`.

For example, if you want to convert SVG to png, your txt file should contains:

```
file-open:1.svg; export-filename:1.png; export-do; file-close
file-open:2.svg; export-filename:2.png; export-do; file-close
```

Syntax is `command`:`arg`; `command2`:`arg2`; etc

You can create this file using your favorite language like C++, Java, C# or Python.

P.S.

It's faster than using `inkscape` command with every file in PowerShell, but don't use it for long time operations because it has a memory leak:
[Link to Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/3479)

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape 1.3 on Windows 10:

1. Open a Windows command prompt.
2. Change to the directory that contains SVG files that you want to convert to PNG.
3. Enter the following command line:

   ```
   for %G in ("*.svg") do ("C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscapecom.com" --export-width=512 --export-height=512 --export-type=png %G)
   ```

#### Using Inkscape shell mode

In their answer, user10609288 wrote:

> For better performance, you should use shell mode

Yes, I agree.

My initial answer, like the example in the question, invokes Inkscape separately for each SVG file.

Instead, you can use the Inkscape shell mode to convert all SVG files in a directory using the same single instance of Inkscape:

```
(for %G in ("*.svg") do @echo file-open:%~fsG;export-width:512;export-height:512;export-type:png;export-filename:%~nG.png;export-do;file-close;) | "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscapecom.com" --shell
```

#### `inkscapecom.com` [sic]? `com.com`? Really?!

Yes, really.

At least, that's the file name in the Inkscape 1.3 (version 0e150ed6c4, 2023-07-21) that I downloaded today (2023-09-12).

I gather that's a mistake. For details, see Inkscape GitLab issue #8893, "[inkscape.com replaced with inkscapecom.com in Inkscape 1.3](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/8893)".

#### Output file name: `*.png` instead of `*.svg.png`

From the question:

> I want ... the name `[SVG File Name].svg.png`

If you decide you would prefer `[SVG File Name].png`, without the `.svg`, then add the following option to the command line:

```
--export-filename=%~nG.png
```

The modifier `~n` extracts the base file name without the file extension.

#### Output image size: relative instead of absolute

I also have SVG files that I want to batch-convert to PNG.

Here's the command line that I use:

```
for %G in ("*.svg") do ("C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscapecom.com" --export-dpi=115 --export-background=#ffffff --export-background-opacity=1.0 --export-type=png --export-filename=%~nG.png %G)
```

or, using Inkscape shell mode:

```
(for %G in ("*.svg") do @echo file-open:%~fsG;export-dpi:115;export-background:#ffffff;export-background-opacity:1.0;export-type:png;export-filename:%~nG.png;export-do;file-close;) | "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscapecom.com" --shell
```

In my case:

- The SVG files render text with a font size of 10pt, to match the size of body text in PDF files.
- The PNG files are for use in contexts that, unfortunately, do not (yet) support SVG. In those contexts, the typical body text size is 16px, corresponding to a larger 12pt size.

To ensure that text in the PNG matches the 16px text in those contexts, I use the `export-dpi` option to increase the size of the image by a factor of 1.2 (12 divided by 10) according to the following calculation:

1.2 * 96 = 115.2

where 96 is, effectively, the DPI of the original SVG.